# Why one of these examples work but not the other?

Tags: python

I am a begginer in Python. I am writting this exercise to practice and found one way to do it, when I thought about doing it another way, it didn't work. It's probably a organization error, but I can't see it. 
 Please take it easy to explain.

```
shuffle(list)
print('The new order is {}'.format(list))
```

That works.

```
print('The new order is{}'.format(shuffle(lista)))
```

That doesn't. I know it's simple but I have no one here to help me solve that doubt.
 Thanks.

Comment: You need to supply your error traceback, variable values and `shuffle` realization code.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that `shuffle` shuffles the list in place, but returns `None` as its value.  Your second syntax requires a new version of the list to be returned.

Also, note that `list` is a built-in type.  Don't use pre-defined identifiers as your personal variables.